# How do I null check object property conditional in flow?

Tags: flowtype

I have some code that looks basically like:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('something')
}
```

Which Flow throws the error `Method cannot be called on possibly undefined value`. Since I've done the check on `serviceWorker` existing, how can I have Flow recognized this is guaranteed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ( typeof navigator.serviceWorker !== 'undefined' )
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: Great, thanks! I forgot that `in` operator will still return true for properties with undefined values.

Comment: even just `if (navigator.serviceWorker)`, `if (navigator.serviceWorker != null)`, or `if (navigator.serviceWorker !== undefined)` depending on your preference will work.